# toJSON() on Date object converting the date back to UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date object like below:

```
Sun Mar 15 2015 02:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST) [epoch = 1426366800000]
```

I need to convert this to a Date JSON format for which I found the function `toJSON()` on the Date object. But this function is converting the time back to UTC time which is causing a problem for our back end. Any suggestions how to fix this.. unable to find any documentation anywhere.

This is what I am currently getting from `toJSON()`:

```
2015-03-14T21:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that the there is no simple and neat way for this than to use momentjs. I had to build out the string using the various formatting options available.. It did work for me but not sure if there a neater way.

Here is my formatter for anyone else who might need this:

```
 var DateObjects = moment()   // current date. You can create for any date.
 var LocalISODateString = DateObjects.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')+'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 var date = "2015-03-14T21:00:00.000Z";
 //toLocaleString will output: 15-‎3‎-‎2015‎ 02‎:30‎:‎00
 var convert = new Date(date).toLocaleString(undefined, {second: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit",  year: 'numeric', day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit"}).replace(/\s/, "T").replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$3:$2:$1"){4})/, "$3")//will parse it to your local time

 //will output: "‎‎2015-03-15‎T02‎:30‎:‎00"
```

Replacing the space with a `T` will make it JSON proof. The `Z` in the JSON string means convert to UTC.

Be sure to choose one consistent date format, either always your locale or store the dates in UTC and convert them back to your locale afterwards.

`toLocaleString` converts the date object to your locale format. A note `options` aren't supported by Safari and only in IE11, Chrome and Firefox are safe.

You can circumnavigate this by doing:

```
 var convert = new Date(date).toLocaleString();
 var splitted = convert.split(T)[0].split("-");
 var convert = splitted[2] + "-" + (splitted[1]) > 10 ? splitted[1] : "0" + splitted[1]) + "-" + (splitted[0]) > 10 ? splitted[0] : "0" + splitted[0]) + "T" + convert.split(T)[1];
```

Which will also yield: `"‎‎2015-03-15‎T02‎:30‎:‎00"`

Comment: Well.. This is always an option.. But I wanted to keep the logic very small and neat so that developers who visit this later understand easily. Also I am kinda averse to these many splits, replaces and other string works.